# How to make AppData directory analog?

Tags: configuration, home-directory, hidden-files, installed-programs

Is there any way to make programs create their own folders ".program_name" not in the home directory, but in some AppData directory?
I do not want to hide hidden files, but at the same time I do not want to see this huge bunch of system folders in my home directory.

Comment: It would seem to require a change to 25+ -year-old Debian standards. Please elaborate on why your preference for seeing every hidden file in /home. --yet not wanting to see *every* file-- is worth this change.

Answer (score 1):

No. Well it is actually yes but you will need to recompile all the software you want this applied to.

Easier option is to flip your problem and approach it differently: why use /home/ for personal data? You can practically sym link anything in your /home/$USER/ to another location. I myself opted to change the directories to a partition /discworld/. It looks like this:

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ cd /discworld/
rinzwind@schijfwereld:/discworld$ ls -a

 .
 ..                                           
 Public
 Desktop                                            
 Templates
 Documents                                         
 Downloads                                          
 user-dirs.dirs
 Videos
 Music               
 Pictures
 .Trash-1000
```

I never use /home/ so never see anything added to /home/ (my / and /home are also on an ssd, and /discworld is a hdd).

Comment: In fact, that's exactly what I was thinking, but I would like to be able to use the alias "~" to my `real_home_directory`.

Comment: You could create a function to redirect the tilde to that new location but yeah, that is annoying indeed :D  Hmm.